# how to array push and implode codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to push array and then implode them

`$this->input->post('sarana')`

this is array for my checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" class="flat" name="sarana[]" id="sarana" value="listrik" />penerangan listrik 
<input type="checkbox" class="flat" name="sarana[]" id="sarana" value="listrik" />penerangan listrik
```

and then I want push input type post mobil /motor /tv

```
<input type="text" name="mobil" placeholder="mobil" class="form-control input-sm">
```

controller

```
$tv=$this->input->post('tv');
$motor=$this->input->post('motor');
$mobil=$this->input->post('mobil');
$sarana=$this->input->post('sarana');
array_push($sarana, 'tv=$tv','motor=$motor','mobil=$mobil');
        $data = array(
            'idakun' =>29,
            'kondisirumah' =>$this->input->post('fisikrumah'), 
            'statusrumah' =>$this->input->post('pemilikanrumah'),
            'sarana' =>implode(",", $sarana),
            'ekonomi' =>$this->input->post('ekonomi'),
            'hpkeluarga' =>implode(",",$this->input->post('hpkeluarga')),

            );
```

but it is giving error as

> array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using array_merge() function.

Just update:

```
$sarana=$this->input->post('sarana');
array_push($sarana, 'tv=$tv','motor=$motor','mobil=$mobil');
```

with:

```
$sarana=$this->input->post('sarana');
$sarana= array_merge($sarana, array('tv'=>$tv), array('motor'=>$motor), array('mobil'=>$mobil));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check for `null` in `$sarana` because if you did not check at least one from checkbox list with the name `sarana[]` then `$this->input->post('sarana')` will give you null value, so-

```
// this will make $sarana as array even if you did not check any of sarana checkbox list
$sarana=($this->input->post('sarana'))?$this->input->post('sarana'):[];
```

Comment: let me know if it did not work for you... if worked please upvote and accept as an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$var= ""; 
      for ($x = 1; $x <= $request->input('cant'); $x++) {
        $array_numerico_indexado = array();
        array_push($array_numerico_indexado, $request->input('cama'.$x));
         foreach($array_numerico_indexado as $numero)
         {
          $var.= $numero.",<br>";
         }
      }
      echo $var;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.